# How do I check an array of objects for a specific property within those objects? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filtering

if i have data that has an array with objects, how do i check each object if it contains a specific property and value? Then creating the possibility to use the data of the ones that do or dont contain the specified property?

This is what i am working with but would like to filter the shoes to the specific rows
project:

[image]

Row.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./Row.css";
import { shoes } from "./data";

function Row({ title }) {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <h2 className="row__title">{title}</h2>
      <div className="row__productsContainer">
        {shoes.map((shoe) => {
          return (
            <div className="row__product">
              <img
                className="row__productImage"
                src={shoe.displayImagesLink}
                alt=""
              />
              <h3 className="row__productName">
                {shoe.brand} {shoe.productName} {shoe.gender}
              </h3>
              <p>${shoe.price}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Row;
```

Shoe data

```
export const shoes = [
  {
    productName: "Air Force One",
    brand: "Jordan",
    price: "110.00",
    trending: true,
    gender: "womens",
    onSale: false,
    origPrice: "",
    newArrival: false,
    displayImagesLink: [
      "https://images.dsw.com/is/image/DSWShoes/498043_100_ss_01?impolicy=qlt-medium-high&imwidth=640&imdensity=2",
      "https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/fG8AAOSwsAtd16dg/s-l300.jpg",
      "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dc844cd51f00b98aff6e6488362ab325-1622582608.jpeg?crop=1.00xw:0.653xh;0,0.347xh&resize=640:*",
    ],
  },
  {
    productName: "Color Vintage Canvas Chuck 70",
    brand: "Converse",
    price: "85.00",
    trending: true,
    gender: "unisex",
    onSale: false,
    origPrice: "",
    newArrival: false,
    displayImagesLink: [
      "https://www.converse.com/dw/image/v2/BCZC_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-cnv-master-catalog/default/dw7116f8fa/images/d_107/171566C_D_107X1.jpg?sw=2000",
      "https://www.converse.com/dw/image/v2/BCZC_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-cnv-master-catalog/default/dw22858a53/images/f_107/171566C_F_107X1.jpg?sw=2000",
      "https://www.converse.com/dw/image/v2/BCZC_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-cnv-master-catalog/default/dwb698b526/images/j_107/171566C_J_107X1.jpg?sw=2000",
    ],
  },
  {
    productName: "Cap Toe Boot",
    brand: "Crown Vintage",
    gender: "Mens",
    trending: false,
    price: "59.99",
    onSale: true,
    origPrice: "79.00",
    newArrival: true,
    displayImagesLink: [
      "https://images.dsw.com/is/image/DSWShoes/500544_225_ss_01?impolicy=qlt-medium-high&imwidth=640&imdensity=2",
      "https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/fG8AAOSwsAtd16dg/s-l300.jpg",
      "https://i.pinimg.com/550x/b5/f4/93/b5f493eeb58458253e9a10ab258e8a9c.jpg",
    ],
  },
  {
    productName: "Classic Lined Clog",
    brand: "Crocs",
    price: "59.99",
    trending: true,
    gender: "Womens",
    onSale: false,
    origPrice: "",
    newArrival: true,
    displayImagesLink: [
      "https://images.dsw.com/is/image/DSWShoes/438702_547_ss_01?impolicy=qlt-medium-high&imwidth=640&imdensity=2",
      "https://images.dsw.com/is/image/DSWShoes/438702_433_ss_02?impolicy=qlt-medium-high&imwidth=640&imdensity=2",
      "https://images.dsw.com/is/image/DSWShoes/438702_433_ss_08?impolicy=qlt-medium-high&imwidth=640&imdensity=2",
    ],
  },
];
```

thank you for the help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+style+title+tooltip+anchor+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. PLEASE do NOT post pictures of code

Answer (score 1):

before map you can add a filter something like this

```
shoes.filter(shoe => shoe["propertyName"] != undefined).map(...
```

accessing a property that doesnt exist will give you undefined so u can filter objects without that property and similarly for a value check you can do

```
shoe["propertyName"] == <desired value>
```

for multiple lists with multiple options you can just run different filters and then map on them.